# How to Activate an alarm in android?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

Am new to android. I am making an application which it will runs on **`AlarmManager`** I have searched many blogs.I got tutorials for activating the **`Alarm`** for few seconds,but in my case i wanted to activate an `Alarm` at a specific time in a day. Could you help me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the difference between the current time and the specific time of day in miliseconds, add it to `System.currentTimeMillis()` . Put this value in `alarmManager.set(type, miliseconds, pendingIntent)`